# Do PostMessage() messages appear in order in Windows?

Tags: windows, mfc, postmessage

The general question, is if I post several messages to the windows message pump from a separate worker thread, will they appear at their destination in the order I sent?  ie..

```
::PostMessage(m_hUsers, WM_BULKPROCESS, 0, 0);
// ... some processing here ...
::PostMessage(m_hUsers, WM_BULKDONE, 0, 0);
```

m_hUsers is a handle (HWND) to a window I'm sending the messages to from my worker thread.  So, will WM_BULKPROCESS always show up first in the window (and therefore be processed by the handler in that dialog class), or is it possible for them to get out of order, ie WM_BULKDONE gets processed before WM_BULKPROCESS, even though it was sent last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window messages are stored in a queue. So you can rely on FIFO mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few exceptions (like WM_PAINT), but generally, the order of messages is kept.
Imaging trying to make sense of mouse input if messages appeared in the wrong order!

Quote from GetMessage

> During this call, the system delivers pending, nonqueued messages,
>   that is, messages sent to windows owned by the calling thread using
>   the SendMessage, SendMessageCallback, SendMessageTimeout, or
>   SendNotifyMessage function. Then the first queued message that matches
>   the specified filter is retrieved. The system may also process
>   internal events. If no filter is specified, messages are processed in
>   the following order:
>
> ```
> Sent messages
> Posted messages
> Input (hardware) messages and system internal events
> Sent messages (again)
> WM_PAINT messages
> WM_TIMER messages
> ```

Answer (score 1):

They should be unless you have code in the message pump that specifically dispatch the messages (either intentionally or not) differently e.g. somehow pick two messages and dispatch them out of order. Normally programmers call DispatchMessage for each message in the order you get from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is synchronization and not the message queue. If your code allows multitple invocations of the worker thread proc you have to manage this more tightly to know which "instance" of the worker thread is posting the messages.

Have you checked to make sure you only one worker thread executing at a time, or that the m_hUsers window handle is protected from being changed between BULKPROCESS and BULKDONE?

SendMessage can be useful for managing the BULKDONE because it will block until the message has been processed allowing the code invoking the worker thread to synchronize the invokation of worker threads and truely know that one worker thread has finsished before invoking another. Postmessage will not block but remember the time sensitive part of your worker thread is
 `// ... some processing here ...
not sending the windows messages.